# Ruby: Working with instance variables within a case statement

Tags: ruby, scope

I'm perplexed as to why I need to selectively refer to an instance variable with "self" inside a case statement inside a class method:

I have a class with an instance method `@working_dir`:

```
class FileSystem
  attr_accessor :sizes, :working_dir
  attr_reader :input

  def initialize(input)
    @input = input.split("\n")
    @sizes = Hash.new(0)
    @working_dir = []
  end
...
end
```

I've defined a method `parse_cmd` that performs an operation on `@working_dir` depending on the outcome of a case statement:

```
...
  def parse_cmd(str)
    cmd_arr = str.split(' ')
    return unless cmd_arr[1] == 'cd'

    case cmd_arr[2]
    when '..'
      working_dir.pop
    when '/'
      self.working_dir = ['/']
    else
      working_dir << cmd_arr[2]
    end
  end
...
```

Rubocop/the interpreter yells at me if I exclude the `self` on `self.working_dir = ['/']`. Why is this? Why do I need to include it here, but not on other references to `@working_dir` within the case statement?

Comment: Here's another example of a situation in which the explicit receiver `self` is required: `class K; def m; self.class == K; end; end`. Then `K.new.m #=> true`. If the line `self.class == K` were replaced with `class == K` then an would be raised when the method `m` is compiled: `SyntaxError: <main>:2: syntax error, unexpected ==`. That's because `class` is a keyword as well as a method. I think there is at least one more case (other than assignments of instance variables) where `self.` is needed, but it does not come to mind. Perhaps it will after I finish this glass of wine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a simple example:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :b

  def initialize(b) 
    @b = b
  end

  def c
    b = 42
  end
end

a = A.new(27)
# => #<A:0x00007f7999088bc0 @b=27>

a.c
# => 42

a.b
# => 27
```

Calling `a.c` is assigning `42` to a *local variable* `b`, and is not modifying the instance variable `@b`.

I'd either need to use `self.b = 42` or `@b = 42` to ensure I am modifying the instance variable.

In your case, you don't need to use `self.working_dir` elsewhere because those uses cannot be construed as assigning to a local variable. Because no local variable `working_dir` exists, the accessor method is used.

Answer (score 2):

In your `case` statement, you are NOT directly refering to the `@working_dir` instance variable. Instead, you are using the accessor methods defined by `attr_accessor :working_dir` at the top of your class.

When calling `attr_accessor`, it will effectively define two methods on your class:

```
def working_dir
  @working_dir
end

def working_dir=(value)
  @working_dir = value
end
```

This allows you to access the value of the instance variable via the method call as if it were a local variable (but it's not, it's always a method call).

Now, in order to call the setter method `working_dir=`, Ruby requires that you call it with an explicit receiver (`self` in your case).

This is because without an explicit receiver, if you assign some value, Ruby will always assign to local variable. With `working_dir = 'value'`, you are thus always creating a local variable named `working_dir` and assign a value to it.

If you use an explicit receiver however, e.g. `self.working_dir = 'value'`, Ruby knows that this can not be a variable assignment anymore and will thus call your setter method.